# Why doesn't meta activity contribute to the Beta badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

I'm curious to know why meta activity doesn't contribute to the Beta badge. Surely if a person is active on meta, they're still actively contributing to the site by participating in meta discussion?

(please tell me if this needs to be on MSE instead)

Comment: Meta has their own badge system. There may be technical limitations (nothing that can't be fixed, but possibly not worth fixing (or adding, since it's technically not broken)).

Answer (score 4):

Mainly because while participating on meta is great, meta is a side effect of the main site. If no one participates on the site and only on meta, we will have no site. Note that there is a separate badge "beta" for only meta activity. This is how most badges work. The only badges awarded on the main site for meta activity is "Convention" and "Quorum".